# How to hide Statics and Functions generated by the lazy_static crate from cargo doc?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rustdoc

I was documenting a module for a rust project that contains 2 lazy_static macro invocations and when evaluating the documentation generated by cargo doc I saw that there was a bunch of Structs, Statics and Functions with a lock beside them that are not in the source code. Is there a way to hide them from the documentation that cargo doc generates?
[Picture of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nERm.png).

I tried adding the `#[doc(hidden)]` attribute to the invocation of the lazy_static macro and it did not work. It did work for the structs generated by lazy_static (which where regular expressions in this case), the appearance of a LAZY struct for each struct would disappear when adding the attribute but the same did not happen when I tried adding it above the macro invocation. I was expecting it to work but instead I get a `unused attribute doc`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a module to completely hide these from documentation:

```rust
#[doc(hidden)]
mod statics {
    use lazy_static::lazy_static;

    lazy_static! {
        pub static ref THING: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3];
    }
}
use statics::*;
```

But I'd recommend using [`once_cell::sync::Lazy`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html) instead, as it is being incorporated into the standard library as [`std::sync::LazyLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.LazyLock.html):

```rust
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;

static THING: Lazy<Vec<u8>> = Lazy::new(|| vec![1, 3, 3]);
```

Comment: I migrated to once_cell::unsync::Lazy and it resolved the issue. Thant you very much.